# Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF682520E81 in while.exe: 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero

Tags: c++, visual-studio

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

long long int a, b = 10, c = 1, res, d = 1, e;

int main() {
    scanf("%lli", &a);
    while (c != 0) {
        res = a % b / c;
        d = res * d;
        e = res + e;
        b *= 10;
        c *= 10;
    }
    //a = d / e;
    printf("%lli", d);
    printf("%lli", e);
    return 0;
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF682520E81 in while.exe: 
0xC0000094: Integer division by zero
```

Вопрос:
В чем ошибка, тк я не делю на ноль вроде бы?

Comment: Это информация :) А вопрос-то в чем?

Comment: В чем ошибка, тк я не делю на ноль вроде бьі

Comment: Пример ввода на котором падает?

Comment: Когда ввожу 36.

Comment: У вас условие с != 0,  когда с увеличивается

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли о том, что деление не только на `c`, но и на `b` — при вычислении остатка... И первым приходит к нулевому значению `b`.

Однако вообще непонятно, что за странная у вас программа, в которой происходит огромное количество переполнений - добавьте после `while` строчку

```
    printf("%lli  %lli\n", b,c);
```

и посмотрите сами...

Comment: Интересно было бы узнать, в чем же я неправ, что знак минус?...